# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, script

Quando eu incluo `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` na parte inferior em partialview recebo aviso no log:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Esse aviso aparece ao abrir modal bootstrap.

Preciso de `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` para validar os campos.

Aqui está o código simples em partialview:

```
@model Projeto.Models.ModeloModels
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Ação", "Controller", new AjaxOptions{ OnSuccess = "OnSuccess"}))
    {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        ...
    }
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Ao remover linha: `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` o aviso desaparece. Alguém sabe o que pode ser esse problema ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema de outra maneira.

Removendo a linha :`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`.

E adicionar esse código no javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").removeData("validator");
    $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
</script>
```